# change src of image every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display same image which is a gif(animated) and jpeg. I am changing the `src` every few seconds.

I see in the dev tools that the src has changed, but the gif does not animate.

```
setInterval(function(){

 if(c == 1){

     imgExt = 'assets/images/resize.gif'
     ++c;
 }
 else{
    imgExt = 'assets/images/resize.jpg';
     --c;
 }
//  document.querySelector('#floorImgId').src = imgExt;
 $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
}, 3000)`
```

It is changing when I inspect element, but in the page, the gif does not play. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.gif` is properly animated?

Comment: check image path, or if possible then give full path to src. or you give 3 second to change image so check your gif should not delay for 3 second.

Comment: Double check the path to the image. Try '/assets/images/resize.jpg';

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `c = 1` to begin with, so that `++c` will work:

(some programmers like to toggle between `0` and `1`, while your original code toggled between `1` and `2`.  Both work and it is up to you.)

Toggling between `0` and `1`:

(I also might have used `prop()` instead of `attr()`, but to keep it close to your original version:)

```js
let c = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  if (c === 0) {
    imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/GCPeHoX.png';
    ++c;
  } else {
    imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/J2wgZZb.png';
    --c;
  }
  //  document.querySelector('#floorImgId').src = imgExt;
  $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="floorImgId">
```

If it is just toggle, I tend to just use:

```js
let toggle = true;
setInterval(function() {

  if (toggle) {
    imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/GCPeHoX.png';
  } else {
    imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/J2wgZZb.png';
  }
  toggle = !toggle;

  //  document.querySelector('#floorImgId').src = imgExt;
  $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="floorImgId">
```

To hide the `toggle` so that it won't contaminate the outer scope, simply wrap the whole thing in an IIFE, or you can also use:

```js
setInterval((function() {
  let toggle = true;

  return function() {
    if (toggle) {
      imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/GCPeHoX.png';
    } else {
      imgExt = 'https://i.imgur.com/J2wgZZb.png';
    }
    toggle = !toggle;

    //  document.querySelector('#floorImgId').src = imgExt;
    $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
  };

}()), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="floorImgId">
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i think you have to increment c in else statement and decrement c in if statement:

```
c=0;
setInterval(function(){

 if(c == 1){

     imgExt = 'assets/images/resize.gif'
     --c;
 }
 else{
    imgExt = 'assets/images/resize.jpg';
     ++c;
 }
//  document.querySelector('#floorImgId').src = imgExt;
 $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="floorImgId" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Hamiltonian_path.svg/440px-Hamiltonian_path.svg.png" />

<script>
var c = 1,imgExt = "";
setInterval(function(){

 if(c == 1){

     imgExt = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Hamiltonian_path.svg/440px-Hamiltonian_path.svg.png'
     ++c;
 }
 else{
    imgExt = 'https://buffer.com/library/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/giphy.gif';
     --c;
 }
 $('#floorImgId').attr('src', imgExt);
}, 3000);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```